# jQuery is firing all elements of same class, how can I fire just the one hovered?

Tags: jquery

I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around this one. I have two divs, one overlays the other exactly. For example sake, lets say the blue div is on the bottom and the red div is on top with it's display property set to none, i'll call this a group. There are also 5 of these 'groups' in a row.

I would like to be able to hover over one, and have the hidden red dive fade in. Currently my code below fires all 5 at the same time, because they all have the same class.

What can I use to solve this problem? I've tried using 'this' inside the hover event and I can't seem to get anywhere.

```
$('.blue').mouseenter( function (){
    $(".red-rollover").fadeIn("500");
});

$('.blue').mouseleave( function (){
    $(".red-rollover").fadeOut("500");
});
```

**edit** 
Sorry I didn't post a fiddle... my bad. This explains the div layout a bit better.
http://jsfiddle.net/pjPua/

Comment: what is the relationship of `.blue` to `.red-rollover` in HTML

Comment: 5 blues, 5 reds. When a blue gets hovered over, the corresponding red displays.

Comment: i added your fiddle with an update to my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would nest the `red-rollover` divs inside the blue and then use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) of [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) to activate them like so:

### e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/K68F5/

### your fiddle, updated with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/pjPua/1/

```
$('.blue').mouseenter( function (){
    $(this).children('.red').fadeIn("500");
});

$('.blue').mouseleave( function (){
    $(this).children('.red').fadeOut("500");
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

try with [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.blue').mouseenter( function (){
    $(this).closest(".red-rollover").fadeIn("500");
    //OR 
   // $(".red-rollover",$(this)).fadeIn("500");
})
```

Comment: the only issue with this is that we do not know the way the divs are set out so the ones being fired off with this may not be the divs corresponding to the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blue').mouseenter( function (){
    $(".red-rollover").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn("500");
});

$('.blue').mouseleave( function (){
    $(".red-rollover").eq($(this).index()).fadeOut("500");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the divs cant fade-in if they are overlayed on top of each other. you need to animate the z-index of the div that you want to fade-in so that it rests on top of each other.

```
('.blue').mouseenter( function (){
    $(".red-rollover").animate({z-index: "2"}, 500);
});

$('.blue').mouseleave( function (){
   $(".red-rollover").animate({z-index: "0"}, 500);
});
```

That should do.

Comment: If they fade out, their display property gets set to none, so you can fade them in and out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the context for you selector this will select `.red-rollover` that is a descendant of the current `.blue`

```
$('.blue').mouseenter( function (){
    $(".red-rollover", this).fadeIn("500");
});

$('.blue').mouseleave( function (){
    $(".red-rollover", this).fadeOut("500");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjPua/2/